# Plotting function ontop of scatter plot in pgf

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following code

`\documentclass[danish,a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgf}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[!h]
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
width=100mm, height=85mm,
  scaled y ticks = false,% xmin = 0.00,  ymin = 0.0,
yticklabel style = {/pgf/number format/fixed,
                     /pgf/number format/precision=3},
tick label style = {font=\footnotesize},
scale only axis,
xmax = 0.85,ymax = 0.28,
      axis lines = left,
      xlabel = {Tid,$s$},
      ylabel = {Hastighed$\frac{m}{s}$}
            ]
\addplot[only marks,mark size=1.5pt] coordinates {
    (0.0,0.0)
    (0.0326,0.0599337793538)
    (0.066567,0.0800334092061)
    (0.099533,0.118183240821)
    (0.1335,0.162894171978)
    (0.166467,0.199695510686)
    (0.199433,0.224502399865)
    (0.2334,0.232532463933)
    (0.266367,0.234484998458)
    (0.300333,0.235156791863)
    (0.3333,0.236558243653)
    (0.366267,0.240320568046)
    (0.400233,0.237211598547)
    (0.4332,0.228133071563)
    (0.467167,0.22779717486)
    (0.500133,0.226828018266)
    (0.5331,0.224762107547)
    (0.567067,0.230861344422)
    (0.600033,0.239829235302)
    (0.634,0.237828910273)
    (0.666967,0.230542213422)
    (0.699933,0.23526158748)
    (0.7339,0.235532932594)
    (0.766867,0.228133071554)
    };
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Scatter Plot over resultater i Bilag 2.}  \label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`

Which generates the following graph [image]
And what I would like to do is add a function ontop of it within the same graph. So I add an extra line of
`\addplot{0.20644-exp(-47.56*x)};`
But when I compile my document my 'graph' begins looking like this[image]

And I can't really understand why it would do that, as I assume I've written the code for my new function correctly, which should look like this [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix this by restricting the domain of your second function, for example:

```
\addplot[domain=0:.8,samples=100]{0.20644-exp(-47.56*x)};
```